# How to plot hex tiles with different length sides?

Tags: hexagonal-grid

I'm trying to create a basic grid of hex tiles. I found some code:

```
s=h/Math.cos(30*Math.PI/180)/2;
tile._x=x*s*1.5;
tile._y=y*h+(x%2)*h/2;
```

That does just that, but I think it's setup for hexes that have same length sides. However, my hex has different length sides. Its width is 140 and its height is 80. How would I change that code to accomodate this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this: if `w,h` are the width and height of your tile image, replace the first two lines of that code sample with just

```
tile._x = x * 0.75 * w;
```

The factor of 0.75 comes from the geometry of hexagons, where the spacing between adjacent columns is 3/4 of the diameter of a single hexagon.  (It's the same origin as the 1.5 in the original code, where `s` was the side length of the hexagon, which is half its diameter.)